# no module name pygame even though I have it on vs code

Tags: python, module, pygame

I was trying to start building game using python, and I am using vs code right now.
I downloaded the pygame, and if I do pip3 list, it shows that I have pygame installed. However, it is keep saying that the no module name is found. I tried to uninstall and install it again, but it is still the same.
What should I do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: By "it" I presume you mean VSCode? It needs telling where python is

Comment: did You restar VSCode?

Answer (score -1):

You may not have switched the development environment in VS Code itself. To do this, click on the button in the lower-left corner in VS Code. Select the version of Python that you installed pygame for.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRXry.png)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have multiple versions of python installed? And does the console output show the path where it is looking for the module?

Try out another version of python by selecting it in the lower left corner like butichex mentioned.